# How can I count articles retrieved by tags

Tags: posts, tags

how can i get posts retrieved by tags, I want to count them. The code i want to use in tabs.

Ex: Movies(3) , Articles(15)

Movies and Articles are Tabs.

I know how to retrieve the count of posts from a custom field.

```
$related_posts = get_field( 'tags' );
$count = 0;
if ( !empty( $related_posts ) ) {
    $count = count( $related_posts );
}
echo $count;
```

How can I count the post retrieved by tags.
Ex: Tag Will Smith - this tag has 6 news

EX: Articles on the page (6)

6 - mean there are 6 articles containing the tag Will Smith

How can I count the articles retrieved.

PS: This is how I retrieve the articles.

```
<?php
$orig_post = $post;
        global $post;
        $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);

        if ($tags) {
            $tag_ids = array();
            foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
            $args=array(
                'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
                'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
                'post_type'=> 'stiri',
                'posts_per_page'=>20, // Number of related news that will be shown.
                'caller_get_posts'=>1

            );}
$recentPosts = new WP_Query($args);
?>
<?php while ($recentPosts->have_posts()) : $recentPosts->the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`WP_Query` has a `post_count` property: [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties).

```
$recentPosts = new WP_Query($args);
$count = $recentPosts->post_count;
```

Comment: not working, i do not use the code in the  Querry, i use in tabs and the tabs are outside the querry...

Comment: You made no mention of tabs in your question. Please revise it accordingly.

Comment: edited vancoder, sorry for that.